# Style of React component is not working on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

**index.jsx**

```
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'

import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'
```

I deployed a `Rails app(Rails + React.js)` on **Heroku**.

But styles of `react-date-range` component are not loaded on **Heroku** even it is working on local.

What is the way to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this using webpacker? Which version of Rails? Are you running a webpack server in development?

Comment: @coreyward yes I am using Webpacker. I am using Rails 6. Yes, running a Webpack server in development.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you're using `Webpack` and you have configs for loading CSS, instead of using `index.jsx` add these two pre-compiled CSS into your root of CSS by this:

```css
@import url("react-date-range/dist/styles.css");
@import url("react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css");
```

If the `url` function doesn't work try without it:

```css
@import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
@import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
```

If these two guys aren't in your final bundle file, simply, use relative path, because it is a little hard to add Webpack configuration that Webpack understand `node_modules` absolute path of libraries inside `css-loader`.

```css
@import "../node_modules/react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
@import "../node_modules/react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
```